# Get label value in a custom Keras Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to get the label for the current input during training, within the call method.
I have the following code, I want to do some action into the if depending on the label.
How can I get the label info?

```
class LatentSpaceManipulationLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(LatentSpaceManipulationLayer,self).__init__()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    pass

  def call(self, latent_vector, training=None):
    b = tf.random.uniform((), minval=0.0, maxval=1.0)

    if b < 0.5: #what is the current label?
      latent_vector *= (1+b) 

    return latent_vector
```

Comment: You can use [tf.name_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/name_scope) with inputs or use "name" parametre in each tensor then you can use a condition to check tensor name to process another logic.